# Epson XP-202 driver for Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, epson

I did install Ubuntu 15.04 today...my printer Epson XP-202 is not working! Am looking for the driver...Does anyone know where I can find it?

Answer (score 0):

You can find Epson printer drivers at [Epson Drivers Site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX)

You need to download deb files according to your architecture and install. It is better to choose "latest", "full feature" drivers, though they do not look latest according to the date.

Generic driver may lack some specific to your model settings.

For 64-bit Ubuntu it is `epson-inkjet-printer-201202w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`

You can find there also scanner drivers and network plugin for scanning through network.

You will need `iscan` and `iscan-data` for the scanner with `ltdl7` in name.

For 64-bit Ubuntu these are:

```
iscan_2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb
iscan-data_1.36.0-1_all.deb
```

For 32-bit same packages with `i386`.

The easiest way to install these packages is to create an Epson directory in your home folder, copy all deb files there and run in terminal:

```
sudo -H dpkg -i ~/Epson/*.deb
```

In case there is an error message regarding `lsb`, run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and all necessary packages will be downloaded and installed.

To setup scanning over the net, you need to install `iscan-network` package, then run

```
sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf
```

And add there a line

```
net <printer_ip_address>
```